# Cucumber Java - Iterate through list of list in Java

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I have my scenerio file like this

```
 Scenario: Login Page with Valid credentials
    Given user is on Application landing page
    Then we verify following user exists
      | name    | email           | phone |
      | Shankar | san@email.com |   999 |
      | Ram     | ram@email.com   |   888 |
      | Sham    | sham@email.org  |   666 |
```

In my step definition, I want to iterate using `for` and `foreach` loop. I tried using `while` loop. It is working fine. Can anyone tell me how to iterate using `for and foreach loop`?

```
@Then("^we verify following user exists$")
public void we_verify_following_user_exists(DataTable datatable)
        throws Throwable {
    List<List<String>> data = datatable.raw();

    Iterator<List<String>> it = data.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

And I'm expecting an output like below

```
name,email,phone
Shankar,san@email.com,999
Ram,ram@email.com,888 
Sham,sham@email.org,666
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate with for loops similar to:

```
for (List<String>currentData : data) {
    org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(currentData, ",")
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Comment: It adds comma after phone column, which is not my expected outpput

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@When("^User enters below credentials$")
    public void user_enters_below_credentials(DataTable credentials) throws Throwable {
        List<List<String>> list = credentials.raw();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i).get(j));
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work for you

```
for(List<String> list: data){
        System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```